# Mapserver - Image Dimensions Don't Match WMS Parameters

Tags: wms, mapserver

Here is the .map file I am using for a simple map with one layer showing the blue marble world:

```
MAP
  NAME   "world"
  CONFIG "MS_ERRORFILE" "/home/balajeerc/Projects/gis_project_Build_Dir/gis_project/data/logs/mapservice_errors.log"
  CONFIG "PROJ_LIB" "/home/balajeerc/Projects/gis_project_Build_Dir/gis_project/deps/proj.4-master/share/proj"
  CONFIG "ON_MISSING_DATA" "LOG"
  DEBUG 5
  EXTENT -180.000 -90.000 180.000 90.000
  SHAPEPATH "/home/balajeerc/Projects/gis_project_Build_Dir/gis_project/data/service_data/data/wms"
  IMAGECOLOR 255 255 255
  SIZE 1350 675

  WEB
    METADATA
      "wms_title" "Georbis WMS Server"
      "wms_author" "MyCompany"
      "wms_onlineresource" "http://10.0.0.8:19090/rasters/world/wms?"
      "wms_enable_request" "*"
      "wms_srs" "epsg:4326 epsg:3857"
      "wms_feature_info_mime_type" "text/html"
      "wms_format" "image/jpg"
    END
  END

  PROJECTION
    "init=epsg:4326"
  END

  LAYER
    NAME world
    TYPE RASTER
    DATA "world.tif"
    EXTENT -180.000 -90.000 180.000 90.000
    METADATA
      "wms_title" "BlueWorld Map"
      "wms_srs" "epsg:4326 epsg:3857"
      "wms_server_version" "1.1.1"
    END
    PROJECTION
      "init=epsg:4326"
    END
  END
END
```

Here is the WMS request I am making to the server:

```
http://localhost:19090/rasters/world/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fjpeg&TRANSPARENT=false&LAYERS=world&mode=map&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&STYLES=&WIDTH=696&HEIGHT=872&BBOX=303302.12823557947%2C-14401959.121379768%2C8834897.477313813%2C-7592337.145509986
```

The trouble is that even though I specify a width and height of 696 and 872 respectively, I always get an image with the original image dimensions, i.e. 1350 x 675.

Why is this the case? Like other WMS servers, I am hoping that Mapserver will also scale the base layer into the resolution I am requesting from it.

Comment: Because you use &mode=map which is forcing MapServer into the native CGI mode instead of WMS. Take it off and read also examples from http://mapserver.org/ogc/wms_server.html. Your BBOX is wrong for CRS=EPSG:4326, you must give it in degrees and lat-lon order for WMS version 1.3.0.

Comment: Metadata item "wms_server_version" is unnecessary in your layer metadata. It belongs to another use case of cascading WMS layers and documented in http://mapserver.org/ogc/wms_client.html.

Answer (score 1):

As @user30184 commented:

> Because you use &mode=map which is forcing MapServer into the native
>   CGI mode instead of WMS. Take it off and read also examples from
>   http://mapserver.org/ogc/wms_server.html. Your BBOX is wrong for
>   CRS=EPSG:4326, you must give it in degrees and lat-lon order for WMS
>   version 1.3.0.
>
> Metadata item "wms_server_version" is unnecessary in your layer
>   metadata. It belongs to another use case of cascading WMS layers and
>   documented in http://mapserver.org/ogc/wms_client.html.